# AVR bootloader reset point

Tags: c, arduino

I have written my own bootloader.
Up until now I have been happy for a watchdog timeout to activate bootloader.
I cannot find information on how to rather jump to beginning of loaded program rather than bootloading mode.

specifics: 328P, 4k bootload allocation, any other info you need?

Comment: A more methodical and clear description of what your AVR is doing now and what you want it to do might be helpful - I'm having a little bit of a hard time understanding the question.  But it sounds like you want to look at the "Boot Reset Vector Enabled" fuse on the handy http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/

Comment: You understood my question perfectly. I feel pretty stupid, because before I reread its description now I thought it made bootloader read only. So this is the one I want?

Comment: Yes, setting the "Boot Reset Vector Enabled" fuse will cause your bootloader code to be run on a reset (triggered by a power on, serial communication, watchdog timout, etc.)  (edited to put into an actual answer)

Comment: thanks! you've sorted me out.

Answer (score 2):

Set the "Boot Reset Vector Enabled" fuse and your bootloader code will be run on reset which can be triggered by applying power, serial communications, watchdog timer, or the reset button)

See http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/ for more fuse programming details.

Comment: Thx very much you and others have helped a great deal! All sorted now :)